# Why isn't this chrome / Greasemonkey script executing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey

I have the following simple Greasemonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name MetaCPAN Everywhere
// @description Add to every link to CPAN a link to MetaCPAN on a Google results page.
// @namespace http://ajct.info
// @match http://*/*
// @version 0.1
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

    var page_links = document.links;
    for (var i=0; i<page_links.length; i++){
        if (page_links[i].href.match(/http:\/\/search\.cpan\.org\/perldoc\?(.*?)$/i)) {
            var match = page_links[i].href.match(/http:\/\/search\.cpan\.org\/perldoc\?(.*?)$/i);
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            span.innerHTML = "&nbsp; <a href=\"http://www.metacpan.org/module/"+match[1]+"\">MetaCPAN</a>";
            page_links[i].parentNode.insertBefore(span, page_links[i].nextSibling);
        }
    }

})();
```

If I run the JavaScript snippet through firebug it does the right thing but if I install it and visit the search results page it doesn't seem to execute the script.

It's presumably something trivial but can anyone point out what I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is that Google ajaxes-in just about all of its results, so you need a way to wait for the first batch and to check for later batches.

There are numerous techniques.  A simple one is to use a timer:

```
//--- This handles both page-load delays, and AJAX changes.
var chkInterval = setInterval (checkForResultsLinks, 500);

function checkForResultsLinks () {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll ('#search a');
    if (links) {

        for (var J = links.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
            var link    = links[J];

            if (link.weHaveProcessed) 
                continue;

            if (link.href.match (/http:\/\/search\.cpan\.org\/perldoc\?(.*?)$/i) ) {
                var match   = link.href.match (/http:\/\/search\.cpan\.org\/perldoc\?(.*?)$/i);
                var span    = document.createElement("span");
                span.innerHTML = "&nbsp; <a href=\"http://www.metacpan.org/module/"+match[1]+"\">MetaCPAN</a>";
                link.parentNode.insertBefore (span, link.nextSibling);
                link.weHaveProcessed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. Google search results appear inside a `div` with the id, "search".
2. Best add the `// @run-at document-end` directive to this kind of script.
3. The current script's`@match` directive is overly broad, the script will fire on every web page!
   You probably want to restrict it to:

   ```
   // @match http://www.google.com/*
   // @match http://google.com/*
   ```
4. There is no need or point to wrapping the code in an anonymous function, like:  `(function() { ... })();` .

Comment: I was actually being an idiot and was installing a cached, broken version. Mine does work but this looks a lot more thorough so I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

I found that some scripts although really simple wouldn't run in chrome, however I did find a chrome extension that fully supports greasemonkey scripts, it's called [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)